# unable to bring up kafka broker on CentOS 7

Tags: java, apache-kafka, centos7

New to Kafka ,I tried installing kafka on Centos server with the below error ,it's a fresh installation and I haven't configured anything to push data to the kafka producer

```
[2016-12-12 18:20:18,531] INFO zookeeper state changed (SyncConnected)     (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2016-12-12 18:20:18,601] INFO Loading logs. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2016-12-12 18:20:18,609] INFO Logs loading complete. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2016-12-12 18:20:18,676] INFO Starting log cleanup with a period of 300000 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2016-12-12 18:20:18,678] INFO Starting log flusher with a default period of 9223372036854775807 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2016-12-12 18:20:18,734] INFO Awaiting socket connections on 172.16.23.13:9092. (kafka.network.Acceptor)
[2016-12-12 18:20:18,770] INFO [Socket Server on Broker 0], Started 1 acceptor threads (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2016-12-12 18:20:18,796] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0], Starting  (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2016-12-12 18:20:18,798] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0], Starting  (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2016-12-12 18:20:18,876] INFO Creating /controller (is it secure? false) (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
[2016-12-12 18:20:18,887] INFO Result of znode creation is: OK (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
[2016-12-12 18:20:18,888] INFO 0 successfully elected as leader (kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector)
[2016-12-12 18:20:18,980] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0], Starting  (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2016-12-12 18:20:18,981] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0], Starting  (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2016-12-12 18:20:18,995] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
[2016-12-12 18:20:18,996] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Startup complete. (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
[2016-12-12 18:20:19,001] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Removed 0 expired offsets in 10 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
[2016-12-12 18:20:19,016] INFO [ThrottledRequestReaper-Produce], Starting  (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledRequestReaper)
[2016-12-12 18:20:19,017] INFO [ThrottledRequestReaper-Fetch], Starting  (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledRequestReaper)
[2016-12-12 18:20:19,024] INFO Will not load MX4J, mx4j-tools.jar is not in the classpath (kafka.utils.Mx4jLoader$)
[2016-12-12 18:20:19,053] INFO Creating /brokers/ids/0 (is it secure? false) (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
[2016-12-12 18:20:19,056] INFO Result of znode creation is: OK (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
[2016-12-12 18:20:19,058] INFO Registered broker 0 at path /brokers/ids/0 with addresses: PLAINTEXT -> EndPoint(172.16.23.13,9092,PLAINTEXT) (kafka.utils.ZkUtils)
[2016-12-12 18:20:19,079] INFO Kafka version : 0.10.0.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2016-12-12 18:20:19,079] INFO Kafka commitId : b8642491e78c5a13 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2016-12-12 18:20:19,080] INFO [Kafka Server 0], started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2016-12-12 18:20:19,082] INFO New leader is 0 (kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$LeaderChangeListener)
[2016-12-12 18:20:20,170] ERROR Processor got uncaught exception. (kafka.network.Processor)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
    at    org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:154)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:135)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:323)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:283)
    at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:472)
    at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:412)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-12-12 18:20:20,180] WARN Unexpected error from /172.16.23.13; closing connection (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.complete(NetworkReceive.java:67)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:136)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:323)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:283)
    at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:472)
    at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:412)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**if i increase the memory then I get the below error.**

```
[2016-12-12 18:18:20,789] INFO Starting log flusher with a default period of 9223372036854775807 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2016-12-12 18:18:20,844] INFO Awaiting socket connections on 172.16.23.13:9092. (kafka.network.Acceptor)
[2016-12-12 18:18:20,848] INFO [Socket Server on Broker 0], Started 1 acceptor threads (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2016-12-12 18:18:20,905] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0], Starting  (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2016-12-12 18:18:20,908] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0], Starting  (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2016-12-12 18:18:20,988] INFO Creating /controller (is it secure? false) (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
[2016-12-12 18:18:20,999] INFO Result of znode creation is: OK (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
[2016-12-12 18:18:21,000] INFO 0 successfully elected as leader (kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector)
[2016-12-12 18:18:21,097] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0], Starting  (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2016-12-12 18:18:21,099] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0], Starting  (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2016-12-12 18:18:21,112] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
[2016-12-12 18:18:21,113] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Startup complete. (kafka.coordinator.GroupCoordinator)
[2016-12-12 18:18:21,117] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 0]: Removed 0 expired offsets in 10 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager)
[2016-12-12 18:18:21,133] INFO [ThrottledRequestReaper-Produce], Starting  (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledRequestReaper)
[2016-12-12 18:18:21,134] INFO [ThrottledRequestReaper-Fetch], Starting  (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledRequestReaper)
[2016-12-12 18:18:21,141] INFO Will not load MX4J, mx4j-tools.jar is not in the classpath (kafka.utils.Mx4jLoader$)
[2016-12-12 18:18:21,168] INFO Creating /brokers/ids/0 (is it secure? false) (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
[2016-12-12 18:18:21,172] INFO Result of znode creation is: OK (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
[2016-12-12 18:18:21,174] INFO Registered broker 0 at path /brokers/ids/0 with addresses: PLAINTEXT -> EndPoint(172.16.23.13,9092,PLAINTEXT)  (kafka.utils.ZkUtils)
[2016-12-12 18:18:21,194] INFO Kafka version : 0.10.0.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2016-12-12 18:18:21,194] INFO Kafka commitId : b8642491e78c5a13 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2016-12-12 18:18:21,195] INFO [Kafka Server 0], started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2016-12-12 18:18:21,200] INFO New leader is 0 (kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$LeaderChangeListener)
[2016-12-12 18:18:30,013] WARN Unexpected error from /172.16.23.13; closing connection (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = 1347375956 larger than 104857600)
    at  org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:91)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:154)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:135)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:323)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:283)
    at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:472)
    at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:412)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Did you enable security for the broker?

Comment: No I haven't explicitly enabled any security feature

Answer (score 1):

Some other process is sending data to kafka. In my case influxdb was sending data to kafka port because kapacitor also listens on 9092 port. so influxdb is sending data to kafka. Once i stopped influxdb no more exceptions.